# Responsive Web Design Detection for Crawler

Tags: python, responsive-design, mechanize, web-crawler

I'm writing a web crawler, but I only care about pages with responsive web design (RWD). Is there a tell-tale sign that the site is responsive? I am using the mechanize module in python. 
The only thing I can think of is grepping the html for something like

```
href="css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

or

```
class="row-fluid"
```

or something that indicates percentages instead of pixels.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could look for media-queries as well... not sure if there is a good standard for check what *is* responsive...

Comment: unfortunately, looking for indicators most likely wont help because you will get a lot of faulty matches. it is easy to look at the css (and potentially js) that is on the page to determine this, but the imported css would be hard to get around unless the site uses the online download rather than having it on their server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My vote would be to search the page head for

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" *** wildcard-selector-here *** >
```

I think it would be easier and more acurate than searching for the presence of CSS media queries.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had a project where I needed to make the website responsive without touching any html markup and no programming code, the only thing I could modify was a stylesheet and a javascript file. I didn't even know which were all the pages of the website because it was a new project to me.

So the goal was to make it responsive so Google crawler won't penalize the site.

So I knew I could use https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/ manually for the pages I wanted to test. But how could I test the whole site?

Well what I've done is to ask for a Webmaster Tools export of the most important links of the site, hundreds of them.

Then I've built a small "tool" that would do exactly what I think Google Responsive Test does, but this tool would accept a list of urls and would loop and test each of them if they fit on a 320px screen (iframe).

This is the HTML tool that you just open, type the urls in a text box, and hit Start! (responsiveChecker.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Responsive Checker</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script>

      var urls;
      var delay=3000;

      google.load("jquery", "1");

      google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {    
        // Place init code here instead of $(document).ready()   
        console.log('jquery loaded');


        $('#responsiveFrame').load(function(){
            if (urls.length > 0) {
              setTimeout(function(){ checkUrl(); }, delay);
            }
        });

      });



      function startChecking() {
        var textUrls=$('#urls').val();
        urls= textUrls.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
        checkUrl();
      }

      function checkUrl() {
        var url;
        if (urls.length > 0) {
          url=urls[0];
          console.log("checking: "+url);
          $('#responsiveFrame').attr('src',url+'#rc=1');
          urls.splice(0, 1);

        } else {
          console.log("no more urls");
        }

      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <iframe id="responsiveFrame" width="320" height="480" src="about:blank" style="border: 1px solid red;" scrolling="no"></iframe>

    <p>
      <label for="urls">Enter URLs to check, one per line:</label><br />
      <textarea id="urls" rows="30" cols="100"></textarea>
    </p>

    <p>
      <input type="button" value="Start checking!" onclick="startChecking();">
    </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

This a script that must be loaded and run on the website you want to check:

```
var responsiveChecker = new function () {
  this.width = 320;
  this.hashParams={};
  this.check = function () {
    this.hashParams=this.parseHashBangArgs();
//    this.log('responsiveChecker');
//    this.log(this.hashParams);
    if (!this.mustCheck()) {
      return;
    } else {

      this.updateParams();

      this.log('must check!');

      var that = this;
      var counter=0;
      var visibleCounter=0;

      jQuery("*").each(function() {
          if (jQuery(this).width() > that.width) {

              if ('SCRIPT' === this.tagName) {
                // ignore script tags
              } else {
                that.log(this.tagName + "#" + this.id);
                counter++;
                if (jQuery(this).is(":visible")) {
                  visibleCounter++;
                  that.log(this.tagName + "#" + this.id);
                }
              }


          }
      });

      var page=window.location.href;

      if (visibleCounter > 0) {
        this.log('[ERROR] page not responsive, there are elements bigger than screen size: '+page);
      } else {
        if (counter > 0) {
          this.log('[WARNING] hey check the above list, there are some hidden elements with size bigger than the screen: '+page);
        } else {
          this.log('[SUCCESS] ¡todo bien! looks like all elements fit on the screen: '+page);
        }
      }

    }
  };
  this.updateParams = function () {
    if (typeof(this.hashParams.width) !== 'undefined') {
      this.width=parseInt(this.hashParams.width);
    }
  };
  this.mustCheck = function () {
    if (typeof(this.hashParams.rc) !== 'undefined') {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };
  // https://gist.github.com/miohtama/1570295
  this.parseHashBangArgs = function() {

    var aURL = window.location.href;

    var vars = {};
    var hashes = aURL.slice(aURL.indexOf('#') + 1).split('&');

    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
       var hash = hashes[i].split('=');

       if(hash.length > 1) {
           vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
       } else {
          vars[hash[0]] = null;
       }      
    }

    return vars;
  };
  this.log = function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  };
};
```

Place this at the end of a jquery ready:

```
responsiveChecker.check();
```

So finally how does it work:

1. You add the responsiveChecker javascripts on the website you want to check
2. You open the responsiveChecker.html file, add the urls of the site in the textarea and hit Start
3. It will start to load the urls in the iframe one by one, and on the Console tab of your browser it will log a "success", "warning" or "error", that means that either it is responsive, or maybe, or not responsive.

Let me know what you think!

By the way, does anybody think this could be useful if we clean it and build a real live tool/service that people could use to test their websites for responsiveness?

Oh btw: The actual checking is done with jQuery, by testing all the elements of the page that have a width smaller or equal to 320px. Indeed this is not 100% guarantee but I think Google's bot might be doing something like this but I'm sure it is more sophisticated.